# Por que a minha variável não altera o valor?

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo

Possuo diversas variáveis e uma delas é o `menor`, ao verificar a saída dela (*output*) eu percebi que a mesma sempre permanece em zero, porque isto está ocorrendo?

```
int z, menor = 0, maior = 0;

                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("informe o valor: ");
                    z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (z <= menor)
                    {
                        menor = z;
                    }
                    else if (z >= maior)
                    {
                        maior = z;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("MAIOR: " + maior);
                Console.WriteLine("MENOR: " + menor);

                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Isto depende da faixa de valores passíveis de serem informados na entrada. O ideal é que você inicialize a variável menor com o maior valor possível para aquele tipo de dado e para a variável maior o menor valor possível de ser informado para o tipo de dado. Outra possibilidade, que independe destes valores máximos e mínimos para o tipo de dado, é você atribuir às variáveis menor e maior o valor lido na primeira leitura e nas leituras seguintes fazer as devidas verificações.

Comment: O que exatamente você está tentando fazer ai?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque você está começando ele com 0, então ele é o menor, só terá um menor que ele se digitar negativo, então tem que começar por um maior, o maior possível (existe outra opção mas para este caso complica a lógica), algo assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int menor = int.MaxValue, maior = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            WriteLine("informe o valor: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) WriteLine("valor inválido");
            if (valor <= menor) menor = valor;
            if (valor >= maior) maior = valor;
        }
        WriteLine("MAIOR: " + maior);
        WriteLine("MENOR: " + menor);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/A6wTD7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zz9cwX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Lesser.cs).

Aproveitei e consertei outros problemas que o código tinha.

Answer (score -2):

Começa a variavel **menor** com o valor digitado do usuário  e depois vai comparando para achar a menor